# Dynamically eval expression using JSTL c:out ${expression}

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jstl

I am using Spring MVC  and looking for a way to evaluate and display a bean property to the UI.

I can use

```
<form:input path="${dynamicExpression}.prop.prop" disabled="true" />
```

but would rather use something like: JSTL c:out

```
<c:out value="${dynamicExpression}.prop.prop"/>
```

This does not work, since is just concats the expression but does not evaluate it.

Any  ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try `${dynamicExpression.prop.prop}`. Moreover, you should better specify a `modelAttribute="user"` (for example) to your `<form:form />`. If you do so, you'll just have to write something like `<form:input path="firstName" />`, and Spring MVC will automatically call `${user.firstName}` on his own.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. No go on `${dynamicExpression.prop.prop}` require something like `${dynamicExpression}.prop.prop.` The dynamicExpression is a variable bean name. I may just have to live with using Spring's `<form:input path="${dynamicExpression}.prop.prop">` this works perfectly, but I dont want to bind anything, just render it to the UI as static text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your bean is in the request, you should be able to do what you want with

```
${requestScope[dynamicExpression].prop.prop}
```